# Add to cart in PHP and MySql

Tags: php, mysql

I am developing an E-Commerce Website using PHP & MySql. I have created products page and categories using PHP & MySql. All is working fine, It shows dynamically product, categories and price.

Now i am trying to add a "Add to Cart Button". Kindly guide me how add to cart button works what are its requirements. I am learning all from internet. I googled a lot but got very confused. Kindly guide me in simple so that i can create this button. Thank in advance

Comment: The `add cart button` would probably send an ajax event and store the current item(s) to the user's `SESSION`. Then update the DOM to show the update/cart added. A bit too broad for SO as is though. Depending on how long you want to store the item and/or if the user is logged in you could write the item to the DB rather than `SESSION`.

Comment: An add to cart button would add the product to a "cart", which could be an array of products in a session variable, or would be a table in a DB. Where are you confused?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `session` to implement this feature. For each product when it is clicked, you can store that product's data on `session`.

Here's some example, I have implemented in object-oriented way in one of my Laravel project: https://github.com/SumonMSelim/laravel5-basic-crud/blob/master/app/Http/Controllers/CartController.php

Let me know if you need some explanation.